# Ignore/overwrite TensorFlow checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on a new TensorFlow problem and using estimators to do so. I like that estimators automatically save checkpoints, as I want to be able to view results in TensorBoard. But, as I tweak things, I don't want my train/evaluate runs on my estimator to pick up from the last checkpoint. Is there an easy way to tell my estimator not to do this? In other words, I want my estimator to ignore and overwrite (essentially, clean out the model dir and start from scratch when I train and/or evaluate.) I don't really see any way to do this via the `config` parameter.

### Follow-up

I've gone ahead and used the `shutil.rmtree` approach as suggested below, and it works a charm. When using a Google Cloud Storage bucket, I use `gsutil -m rm -rf <path-to-delete>`.

Comment: `train()` starting from scratch makes sense; can you just set `model_dir` to `tempfile.mkdtemp`? Evaluation starting without a checkpoint would just leave uninitialized variables.

Comment: But I want to view results _easily_ in TensorBoard. With this approach, I’ve got to always track the temp directory I’m using...

Comment: Makes sense. And what about just `shutil.rmtree` on the checkpoint directory just prior to training? This is probably doable as a training hook in the Estimator, but I'm trying to figure out why the Estimator needs to do it.

Comment: Fair point. That should work just fine.

Comment: I'm also having problems with a similar problem. I want to overwrite my tensorboard folder if the tag for the current training has not changed (i provide it on the CLI). rmtree doesn't seem to work, unless I am in debugger mode. very odd behavior!